# Android Emulator: both soft input and hard keyboard input

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I would like to have both soft input and hard keyboard enabled in my android virtual device. I know how to have either but not **BOTH**.

The reason wanting for **BOTH** at the SAME time:

- soft input: preview how the layout resizes when the screen is reduced by the keyobard
- hard keyboard: obviously the quick input.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your AVD manager Tab then select the appropriate AVD then refer the "hardware menu" in that click on new button and select the keyboard support option to enable hardware keyboard.

Hope this is helpful to you.

yash.

Comment: Hi Yash, the main part of this question is I want BOTH soft and hard

Comment: Please Refer the below link it might helpful to you.http://www.pdfdownload.org/pdf2html/view_online.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fgrail.cba.csuohio.edu%2F~matos%2Fnotes%2Fcis-493%2Flecture-notes%2FAndroid-Chapter07B-Hard-Soft-Keyboard-IMF.pdf

Comment: thank you. nice reference. I like the explanations, could you direct me to where it comes from so I could browse available topic?